# Cannot see color panel in JSColor object in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, jscolor

I am using [JSColor](http://jscolor.com/try.php) to allow users to select a color, but I am running into a wierd issue. On my IE 8 browser, I am not able to see the color panel (highlighted in red circle in the image below).  Would anyone know if this is a bug in the color panel ? Same issue in Chrome, so I would not think this is broswer specific.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for this issue is to download the following 3 images and to copy them to your webserver next to your jscolor.js file.

- http://jscolor.com/jscolor/hs.png
- http://jscolor.com/jscolor/cross.gif
- http://jscolor.com/jscolor/arrow.gif

The reason that this is not mentioned at jscolor.com is probably that they want to track where their jscolor script is running, since the script tries to download these 3 images from their webserver.

Comment: Sorry about the format but I stackoverflow did not allow me to post the message in "normal" format.